# How to set virtual host in apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to setup the virtual host in apache web server on Ubuntu. For this I followed lot of tutorials and did exactly the same step. But could not find the reason why it is not working for me.

For Now see the following youtube tutorial:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfRJ4e8UQfQ
```

I followed this tutorial and did exactly the same as in video. But still when I type testdomain.com on browser it does not show any thing from local machine. Instead of it looks for Internet domain. 
Do I need to entry something in host file.

Please guide to find out problem why it is not working for me on ubuntu-14. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `/etc/hosts` file. Append `127.0.0.1 testdomain.com`, save and restart the browser.

Comment: I added 127.0.0.1 testdomain.com this entry into /etc/host.conf file. But still not working.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, then you need to edit `/etc/hosts` as I mentioned in the answer, and not `/etc/host.conf`...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was confused with file name and was looking for hosts.conf. But its only hosts .

Comment: You're welcome, if that solves your issue please accept the answer

Comment: One more thing, can we have multiple mapping within this file. like 127.0.0.1 mytest.com can also we added with same IP.

Comment: Yes, as well you can have multiple domains sharing the same line, like `127.0.0.1 test1.com test2.com`